# add extra "state" when creating Laravel model (similar to factory state)?

Tags: php, laravel

Would like to pass extra information when a model is being created. This so that this information is used by the model to set certain model attributes. Similar to how [factory states](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-states) are used.

In my case: would like to do something like:

```
User::keys('my password')->create([...])
```

Where the keys method would take the argument to define certain Model attributes.
For a factory [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-states) shows it would be something like:

```
public function keys($password)
{
    return $this->state(function (array $attributes) use($password) {
        return [
            'key' => myMethodToCreateAKey($password),
        ];
    });
}
```

I'm building a trait for the User model that includes the logic for creating the key.
So, **don't** want to set the key as part of the user create array, like:

```
User::create([..., 'key'=>myMethodToCreateAKey('my password')])
```

Is there a way to achieve that? Currently I am building my own chainable method that stores the variable and uses it at the time of `booted( static::creating(...))`. Was hoping there's a more official way, similar to factory states.

Comment: Why wouldn't just making a trait with a state method in it work for you?

Comment: That's what I am doing, but that feels like reinventing the wheel knowing something is available for factories already. Therefore: wanted to check if there is a more official way.

Comment: If you `keys` method in the trait is always going to be the same and you're going to use it with a few different factories then it makes complete sense. If not, then I feel I'm missing something.